# Got status code = 11 on APNS notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm handling the error APNS send back after I write a notification.
According to the documentation, the error code should be 1-10 or 255.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

However, I got the package back:
080b00000000
The command is 8 which fits the documentation but b = 11 which is not documented
Does anyone encounter this before as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too.

My  'Notification identifier' item in the frame wasn't well formed.

The 'Item data length' must be the size of the binary version of your identifier.